# Varchar Sql Server Sum

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have ms access database and i want convert Sql Server.

My txttotal column have a (`15,50 1,25 10,00`) value
My Sum function great work my old access database this query:

```
 dtfr = DateTimePicker1.Value 
 dtto = DateTimePicker2.Value



sqlcmd = "SELECT SUM(txttotal) as Total from table WHERE odate >=  CDate('" + dtfr + "') AND  odate <= CDate('" + dtto + "')"
```

Access retrieve True value (26,75)

But i tried Sql Server using this query:

```
sqlcmd = "SELECT SUM(CAST(txttotal as ?)) as Total from table WHERE odate BETWEEN '" + dtfr + "' AND '" + dtto + "'"
```

?= I tried float,int,double

SqlException "**Error converting data type varchar to float**"

**Edit: my txttotal column is varchar**

Comment: Are you sure it's not a culture thing? Did you try using . instead of , for your decimal separator?

Comment: I need use (,) character for money separator.

Comment: Are you using c# or vb.net?

Comment: Also, it's not clear in the question what the `txttotal` column contains. Is the sample in the question a sample of one row, or is it a sample of 4 rows separated by commas? On top of that, it's not clear how you want sql server to interpret some of those values. For example, should `50 1` value be interpreted as `50` or `501`?

Comment: Finally... the code as written is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. _Never_ use string concatenation to substitute user-supplied data into a query, and of course the best fix for your problem is _fix the schema_ to store numeric data in numeric columns.

Comment: I use VB.NET Visual basic, my values 15,50 10,00 25,50 4,00 etc..

Comment: I want total sum but my column is varchar, if i convert sql column money type and Sum(CAST (txttotal AS DECIMAL(17,2))) .. then great work. But if i convert my column type, I have a lot of work :(

Comment: Please answer my question more specifically. For a value in the column of `50 10`, do you want `50`, `5010`, `50` and `10` both included, or is there a space instead of a decimal separator (ie: `50.1`/`50,1` depending on culture)?

Comment: And "lot of work" or not, you should convert the column type. It is the by far the best overall solution.

Comment: One more question: if the space is a decimal separator, what version of Sql Server are you using? The fix for this will change dramatically if you're using Sql Server 2012 or later.

Comment: I have sql server 2012 express your sql query very professional i like it and i choosing this. but i think my one way change my column type?

Comment: because gives varchar to integer conversion error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION TO PUT DATA INTO SQL QUERIES!**

That leads to Sql Injection attacks. The question is totally clear on what values you need, but guessing that the sample is 4 records separated by commas and that you only want the portion before the space in each record, do it like this instead:

```
Dim sql As String = _
     "SELECT SUM(CAST(LEFT(txttotal, " & _
          " CASE WHEN charindex(' ', txttotal) = 0 THEN LEN(txttotal) ELSE charindex(' ', txttotal) - 1 END " & _
         " ) As Integer)) as Total" & _
     " FROM table WHERE odate >=  @DateFrom AND  odate <= @DateTo"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value 

    cn.Open()
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    'Do something with the reader here

End Using
```

or for a DataSet/DataTable solution:

```
Dim result As New DataTable
Dim sql As String = _
     "SELECT SUM(CAST(LEFT(txttotal, " & _
          " CASE WHEN charindex(' ', txttotal) = 0 THEN LEN(txttotal) ELSE charindex(' ', txttotal) - 1 END " & _
         " ) As Integer)) as Total" & _
     " FROM table WHERE odate >=  @DateFrom AND  odate <= @DateTo"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value 

    cn.Open()
    result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

End Using
```

---

Based on some comments, it's beginning to sound like the space is simply a missing decimal separator. If that's the case, `SUM()` expression is pretty simple:

```
 SUM(CAST(REPLACE(txttotal, ' ', '.') As numeric(5,2)))
```

where you may need a `,` instead of a `.` depending on the culture installation of the server. Sql Server 2012 also has a new `PARSE()` function that allows you specify the culture, removing any chance for ambiguity if an upgrade changes the systems local culture.

Answer (score 1):

Allthough i'm not a fan of holding data that way, but it sounds that you've historic reasons.
For SQL Server 2005+ (2008+ ?) you have the possibility to convert your "varchar" column to valid xml and execute SQL expressions over it. There are other possibilities, but therefore you have to use procedural code (stored procedures/user defined functions) and/or temporary tables ore table variables to split your date into tabular form.

Because the resulting query is not so easy to follow i'll start with an example where you have the content of one txttotal value in a variable of type varchar.

First of all, convert "txttotal" to a valid xml-fragment (you have to add start and end tags und also have to replace your "," decimal separator to "." and cast the result to an XML data type.

Now it is possible to select all "" nodes "... FROM @xmltotal.nodes('/v') ..." from that xml variable, perform an XQuery expression "... p.value('.', 'FLOAT') ..." on them to convert/cast them to T-SQL data type "FLOAT" and finally SUM() that values up.

```sql
DECLARE @txttotal VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xmltotal XML

SELECT @txttotal = ' 15,50 1,25 10,00 '
SELECT @xmltotal = CAST('<v>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@txttotal)),',','.'),' ','</v><v>')+'</v>' AS XML)
-- -> <v>15.50</v><v>1.25</v><v>10.00</v>

SELECT SUM(p.value('.', 'FLOAT')) FROM @xmltotal.nodes('/v') t(p)
```

All that above can be used to write one declarative SQL statement which meets your requirements ...

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(p.value('.', 'FLOAT')) FROM xmltotal.nodes('/v') t(p))
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CAST('<v>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(txttotal)),',','.'),' ','</v><v>')+'</v>' AS XML) AS xmltotal
        FROM
            Table
        -- WHERE
        -- add your required condition here!
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a split string function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

Now use `cross apply` to pass the values to `function` and split it before aggregating. Try something like this

```
SELECT Sum(item) AS Total 
FROM   table 
       CROSS apply dbo.Splitstrings(txttotal, ',') sp 
WHERE  odate BETWEEN x AND y
```

Check the below links to create a split string function

1. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
2. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: sum işleci için işlenen veri türü varchar geçersiz. Translate: The type of data processed for juice processors varchar is invalid.

Comment: Edit: my txttotal column is varchar